# How to split data from StringField

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, split, flask-wtforms

I have registration form where users can put their first name, last name, email and password.
I'm trying to get that email and split it to get the domain and check my database if that email already registered, but i'm not able to split the data, no matter what I change I keep getting different errors.

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField(
        "First Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)]
    )
    last_name = StringField(
        "Last Name", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)]
    )
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField(
        "Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("password")]
    )
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")

    # Here i'm trying to split the email so I can use the domain.
    domain = email.split("@")[1]

    def validate_email(self, email, domain):
        user_email = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        org_domain = Organization.query.filter_by(domain=domain.data).first()
        if user_email:
            raise ValidationError("That email is taken. Please choose a different one.")
        elif org_domain:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Your domain is managed by someone else, please contact your administrator. If you need help please contact our support"
            )
```

routes.py

```
@users.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for("main.dashboard"))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode(
            "utf-8"
        )

        organization = Organization(
            domain=form.email.data.split("@")[1],
        )
        db.session.add(organization)
        db.session.commit()
        admin = User(
            first_name=form.first_name.data,
            last_name=form.last_name.data,
            display_name=form.first_name.data + " " + form.last_name.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=hashed_password,
            org_id=organization.id,
        )
        db.session.add(admin)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your account has been created! You are now able to log in", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("users.login"))
    return render_template("users/register.html", title="Register", form=form)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Please don't make us guess.

Comment: Why are you splitting it in register() method?

Comment: I tried | domain = email.split("@")[0] | and I got 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'split'
I tried | domain = email.data.split("@")[0] | and got 'UnboundField' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: I also tried to put | domain = email.split("@")[1] | inside | def validate_email(self, email): |
but I got 'StringField' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by splitting it under def validate_email(self, email):

```
    domain = str(email).split("@")[1]
    domain = domain.split('"')[0]
```